# Node.js, simple TLS client/server

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, ssl, tls1.2

I want create a simple secure client/server using TLS. I've follow instruction on the [official doc](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html). But I don't know how to create self-signed certificate with openssl (does not work with me).

Here code :

server.js

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if using the client certificate authentication.
  requestCert: true,

  // This is necessary only if the client uses the self-signed certificate.
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') ]
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  socket.write('welcome!\n');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

client.js :

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  // Necessary only if using the client certificate authentication
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),

  // Necessary only if the server uses the self-signed certificate
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ]
};

const socket = tls.connect(8000, options, () => {
  console.log('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.on('end', () => {
  server.close();
});
```

I don't know why use two different key-pair :

- client-key.pem
- client-cert.pem

and :

- server-key.pem
- server-cert.pem

Anyone can exmplain me ? For work in self-signed.

Sincerely,

Yoratheon